# Whats your favorite map projection for

Tags: coordinate-system, mapping, reprojection-mathematics

What is your a nice projection for the southern Atlantic? S.America & W. Africa?
I'm looking to produce nice maps with little distortion on shapes. Leaning toward Lambert.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "What's your favorite ...?" questions are explicitly off-topic in the Help Center. See https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask.

Comment: Obligatory [XKCD reference](https://xkcd.com/977/)

Comment: She does get more specific in the body of the question. Yes, Lambert conformal conic could work. For the S Atlantic, an oblique stereographic (also conformal) might work too.